# How can I read the store inside the Firebase onAuthStateChanged callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, state

I've been trying to fix my code with no luck so far. Here is my problem and I would really appreciate your help.

1- in my top index js, I create a store and call store.dispatch(startListeningToAuthChanges())

2- Stateless startListeningToAuthChanges definition:

```
export const startListeningToAuthChanges = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {

// listen from Firebase
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

  if (user) {

    // I am already saving displayName to the store in another file and would like to read it from the store so that I can push it to Firebase. I have no idea how I can read it from the store. I tried "connect" but I keep getting undefined.

    usersRef.child(user.uid).set('Need to set displayName here'));
  } else {
    dispatch(signedOut());
  }
})
```

};
};

Comment: Have you tried ‘getState()’ https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState ?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that and use connect instead. I saw many times getState described as an anti-pattern. Not sure if it is true though. Also is it safe to include the store in the component knowing that you can have access through connect. I just can't make connect work for some reason using mapStateToProp.

Comment: Ah okay. Can you post your code that includes the `connect()`.

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {UserInfo: state.UserInfo}
}

//UserInfo has been saved before in another component
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(startListeningToAuthChanges)